# replace a string of characters with the line number

Tags: perl, sed, awk, printf

I have a text file that has approximately 3,000 lines.  99% of the time I need all 3,000 lines.  However, periodically I will grep out the lines I need and direct the output to another text file to use.

The only problem I have in doing so, is:  Embedded in the text file is a 6 character string of numbers that indicate the line number.  In order to use the file, this area needs to be correctly renumbered...(I don't need to re-sort the data, but I need to replace the current six characters with the new line number.  and it must be padded with zeros! Unfortuantely the entire rows is one long row of data with no field separators!

For example, my first three rows might look something like:

```
20130918082020ZZ000001RANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCDEFGH
20130810112000ZZ000999MORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCD
20130810112000ZZ000027SILLMORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHIS
```

The six characters at positions 17-22 (Immediately following the "ZZ"), need be renumbered based on the current row number...so the above needs to look like:

```
20130918082020ZZ000001RANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCDEFGH
20130810112000ZZ000002MORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCD
20130810112000ZZ000003SILLMORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHIS
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
KSL.

Comment: Will the `RANDOMDATAFOLLOWS` always going to be A-Z or could it be digits?

Comment: The Text after the Line number is formatted STRING data and NUMBERS.  The software that reads this file parses out the data and imports the data into various tables in a database.  If my sequence is out or order, the software detects this and corrects; but will fill the log file with an error for each row that is not correct (which, in this case, is all of them!).  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with Perl. It assumes that the numbering is always 6 digits after the `ZZ` sequence.

In convert.pl:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $i = 1; # or the value you want to start numbering
while (<STDIN>) {
    my $replace = sprintf("%06d", $i++);
    $_ =~ s/ZZ\d{6}/ZZ$replace/g;
    print $_;
}
```

In data.dat:

```
20130918082020ZZ000001RANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCDEFGH
20130810112000ZZ000999MORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCD
20130810112000ZZ000027SILLMORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHIS
```

To run:

```
cat data.dat | perl convert.pl
```

Output

```
20130918082020ZZ000001RANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCDEFGH
20130810112000ZZ000002MORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHISABCD
20130810112000ZZ000003SILLMORERANDOMDATAFOLLOWSAFTERTHIS
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer so others know your question is solved.

Comment: +1. If you change `while (<STDIN>)` to `while (<>)` you can invoke your script like `perl convert.pl data.dat` in addition to your style.

Comment: For the golfing crowd, this can be boiled down to: `perl -pe 's/ZZ\K\d{6}/sprintf "%06d",++$i/e'`

Comment: heh, can save 2 chars: `perl -pe 's/ZZ\K\d{6}/sprintf "%06d",$./e'`

Answer (score 1):

If I would solve this, I would create a simple python script to read those lines by filtering as grep does and using a internal counter from inside the python script.

As simple hints you can read each line in a string and access them using variablename[17:22] (17:22 is the position of the string you are trying to use).

Now, there is a method in the string in python which does the replace, just replace the values by the counter you create.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've never used Python..."Google'ing" it now...but looks pretty complicated; I was hoping to use SED or awk, but wasn't sure how to pad to 6 characters...  Thanks for the prompt response!  KSL.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in awk:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,16) sprintf("%06d", NR) substr($0,23)}'
```

or

```
gawk 'match($0,/^(.*ZZ)[0-9]{6}(.*)/,a) {print a[1] sprintf("%06d",NR) a[2]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of thing where [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $line = <> ){
  chomp $line;
  my @elem = unpack 'A16 A6 A*', $line;

  $elem[1] = sprintf '%06d', $.;
  # $. is the line number for the last used file handle
  say @elem;
}
```

Actually looking at the lines, it looks like there is date information stored in the first 14 characters.
Assuming that at some point you might want to parse the lines for some reason you can use the following as an example of how you could use [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) to split up the lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10.0; # say()
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my @date_elem = qw'
  year month day
  hour minute second
';
my @elem_names = ( @date_elem, qw'
  ZZ
  line_number
  random_data
');

while( my $line = <> ){
  chomp $line;
  my %data;
  @data{ @elem_names } = unpack 'A4 (A2)6 A6 A*', $line;

  # choose either this:

  $data{line_number} = sprintf '%06d', $.;
  say @data{@elem_names};

  # or this:

  $data{line_number} =  $.;
  printf '%04d' . ('%02d'x5) . "%2s%06d%s\n", @data{ @elem_names };

  # the choice will affect the contents of %data

  # this just shows the contents of %data
  for( @elem_names ){
    printf qq'%12s: "%s"\n', $_, $data{$_};
  }

  # you can create a DateTime object with the date elements
  my $dt = DateTime->new(
    (map{ $_, $data{$_} } @date_elem),
    time_zone => 'floating',
  );

  say $dt;

  print "\n";
}
```

Although it would be better to use a regular expression, so that you could throw out bogus data.

```
use v5.14; # /a modifier

...

my $rdate = join '', map{"(\\d{$_})"} 4, (2)x5;
my $rx = qr'$rdate (ZZ) (\d{6}) (.*)'xa;

while( my $line = <> ){
  chomp $line;
  my %data;
  unless( @data{ @elem_names } = $line =~ $rx ){
    die qq'unable to parse line "$line" ($.)';
  }

...
```

It would be better still; to use [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) added in [5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Named-Capture-Buffers).

```
...

my $rx = qr'
  (?<year> \d{4} ) (?<month> \d{2} ) (?<day> \d{2} )
  (?<hour> \d{2} ) (?<minute> \d{2} ) (?<second> \d{2} )
  ZZ
  (?<line_number> \d{6} )
  (?<random_data> .* )
'xa;

while( my $line = <> ){
  chomp $line;
  unless( $line =~ $rx ){
    die qq'unable to parse line "$line" ($.)';
  }
  my %data = %+;

  # for compatibility with previous examples
  $data{ZZ} = 'ZZ';

...
```